# Why does java.awt.Point return a double for both getX() and getY() instead of int?

Tags: java, graphics, point

Both x and y are defined as int in class Point. Why then are the methods `getX` and `getY` returning `double`?

Thankfully x and y are exposed as public so we need not cast to int to get the values as such but curious why these methods do not return int.

Answer (score 4):

Because it inherits the `Point2D` class which defines them as returning double.

It also defines 2 inner classes which stores the values as floats and doubles, respectively.

Old classes can look weird after 20+ years.

Comment: I see no sense in representing pixel locations on screen as anything but int ... What is the rationale of using double precision?

Comment: @Constantin Who said anything about pixels?

Comment: Is there a more suitable class in Java to represent an x and y location in terms of pixels?

Comment: I wouldn't use a class to represent a pixel. That's very slow and wasteful. What's your actual problem?

Comment: @Constantin `Point2D` objects can represent any point in a 2D coordinate space. You would use `Point2D.Double` or `Point2D.Float` to represent things like geographic or geometric coordinates, and `Point` to represent integer coordinates like locations of pixels or cells in grids etc.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic, that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It inhereted from the java.awt.geom.Point2D wich contains abstract #getX.

```
public abstract double getX();
```

Why it was done by this way I'm wondering too. Maybe here is the answer:

```
@since 1.2
```